# How to range-check luma in After Effects?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, final-cut-pro-x, adobe, final-cut-pro

Where do I find the luma range clip indicator that I have in Final Cut?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new **adjustment layer** at the top of your composition, with the Levels effect set to the following:

- Input Black: `254`
- Input White: `255`

[image: Levels effect]

This will have the result of causing any luma values that were below 254 to become **black**, while anything above it becomes **white**. Here is an example of it over a fractal noise pattern:

#### Before

[image: Before image]

#### After

[image: After image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a way to get zebras on your output, but the Lumetri Scopes will give you a video signal that will show you whether your luma is too high.

https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/color-correcting-video-lumetri-scopes/

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not helping. I need to know exactly where in the image the luma is clipping. I have demonstration-videos shot on white background and I need to make that background be absolute white (255,255,255).

Comment: I would adjust the levels on the shot until I can see that the Luma levels are at absolute white on the scopes.